# How to could I get list of my subscribers in C# using Youtube API V3?

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-api

I want to make an app that can show me the list of my current subscribers, I want to get the channel id. I have seen the Doxygen docs, but I can't get how to work with the API.

I have tried to access the subscriber methods, but I'm not sure what to pass so I can retrieve my subscribers.

```
var mysubscribers = new Subscription().SubscriberSnippet;
       mysubscribers.ChannelId= "subscriberSnippet"; // - is that correct, what I need to pass?
        Console.WriteLine(mysubscribers);
```

Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Press any key to continue...

Comment: you need to find out the ID of your channel, it is usually part of the url for your channel, for example this url `https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCqJ-Xo29CKyLTjn6z2XwYAw` shows that the channel id is `UCqJ-Xo29CKyLTjn6z2XwYAw`

Comment: Do you have working example? I have tried to pass my channel id to the ChannelId, but I don't get results. I have json file with OAuth 2 and scope set to YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeForceSsl.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)